# MPI scatter operation not returning correct result

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi, hpc

I'm using `MPI_Scatter` to send some arrays from one process (master) to all the others (workers). Some of the receive buffers seem to be empty (they are 0, most likely uninitialized). The values seem to be not assigned to the correct elements of the correct arrays, if assigned at all.

Basically, as shown below, I'm trying to send an array of size N from the master process to all other processes.

```
MPI_Scatter(A, N, MPI_DOUBLE, A_buff, N, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

My code is here: https://github.com/olavurmortensen/distributed_nmf/blob/master/main.c

The scatter operations are at line 157. Arrays are allocated using `malloc`.

Comment: Are you sure what you're trying to achieve here doesn't correspond to a `MPI_Bcast()` rather than a `MPI_Scatter()`? The former send the whole data to every processes, while the latter distribute shares of it to all processes.

Comment: Each process needs it's own copy of the matrix, so `MPI_Scatter` is appropriate, if I understand correctly.

Comment: The scatter operation returns `MPI_SUCCESS` (or actually 0), so the problem isn't that the operation is failing entirely.

Comment: If it's a copy that each process needs, then you need to use `MPI_Bcast()`. If each processes needs it small sub-part of the global matrix, then you need `MPI_Scatter()`

Comment: That is exactly what was wrong, I misread the first one. Thanks for clarifying. Feel free to write it as an answer so you can get some precious precious internet points =)